# Wordpress magazine

Tags: wordpress

I need to create a magazine publication in Wordpress. One issue contains cover + articles. No comments or anything fancy needed. The cover has the index of articles and each article has a content and a picture and description of the author. The author doesn't need to be a real user, it can be just a block with a picture and a description.
I know how to do this in Drupal, I would create content types with specific fields for each type and prepare the templates accordingly. I would setup menus to reflect hierarchy. To show the authors section below the article I would use custom picture fields and text.
So adding and issue would be as simple as creating a page-cover and page-articles, and setting menus accordingly.

How can I accomplish this in Wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is roughly the solution I found:

Create "Article" post type. Add all the necessary fields.
Create a "Cover" post type. Add all the necessary fields.
Create an "issue" taxonomy term. All articles belonging to the same volume will be linked through this term. There's one cover per issue.
Also, install the Co-Author plugin (in case there's more than one author per page).